# How to generate a timespan column based on a DateTimeStamp column using Python's pandas?

Tags: python, timestamp

The following is a subset of the data table that I have:

```
DateTimeStamp            Action          
04/16/20 07:29:22:778    X                   
04/16/20 07:29:23:918    Y               
04/16/20 07:29:25:118    Z               
.                       .       .
```

The following is a subset of the data table that I aim for:

```
DateTimeStamp            Action          Duration of action in milliseconds
04/16/20 07:29:22:778    X                   
04/16/20 07:29:23:918    Y               1.140
04/16/20 07:29:25:118    Z               2.340
.                       .       .
```

I would be happy to know how to use pandas/numpy to do that.

Comment: Look into [`pandas.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for your help!